# Why is a static const in the header defined as const in the code file

Tags: c++

If I am correct a static constant member in a class is defined like this:

```
// header file, inside a class definition:
static const SomeType my_const;

// cpp file
const ClassName::SomeType my_const = SomeType(5.0);
```

Now I don't understand why the classifier is not present in the cpp file. The signature doesn't match so to say, and I don't want to OCD over it too much but what is the reasoning behind this?

For the curious, when I do add static this is the error message I get:

```
error C2720: 'static ' storage-class specifier illegal on members
```

Comment: You can read about static members @ [Static Members, Classes Tutorial, cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/#static) Inside of a class/struct the value is declared static but the definition of a static member (variable or function) must not have the static specifier again.

Comment: `static` is not part of the type, it is only needed on the declaration, to indicate it's not a normal member, it doesn't serve any purpose to repeat it on the definition (and is not allowed.)  `const` is part of the type, so must be repeated on the member's definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` is a massively overloaded keyword, it has at least 4 different meanings and more to look after. No wonder you are confused.

Your first line is not just standing in the header, but is within a class. (please edit the code).  In a class you can have normal members, and ones that are shared between instances. To mark that `static` was the choice.

At namespace scope the keyword means completely different thing, namely it turns the linkage to internal.  As definition ios made at that scope you must not add that "version" of static.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed inside a class definition. I updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt that is it -

```
const ClassName::SomeType my_const = SomeType(5.0);
```

OR `const SomeType ClassName::my_const = SomeType(5.0);`

In very simple terms:-

'static' is a storage type its not a data type or a modifier, here it was just to tell the compiler that this should be shared in all the instances of the object which means to create only one instance of it. We do not include storage type in the signatures.

Answer (score -1):

const SomeType ClassName::my_const = SomeType(5.0);